Reasons for org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No enum constant com.foo.bar.Company
We have an enum class on the project we've been using for years, and it has had no changes.
This enum class is used as the type for mapping one column using JPA.
The class has current values such as:
public enum Company {
  ACME, CYBERDYNE, INGEN, MONSTERS_INC
}

And then on our table, there's one non-nullable column that gets any of those values.
After today's automatic data sync, we started getting this error:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No enum constant com.foo.bar.Company.

What could be the reason?

In this case, the issue was that we were receiving empty ('') values on the column and JPA was trying to map that to an empty Enum value, which didn't exist.
Removing the rows with empty data solved the issue.
